# Safari browser , text box height scroll or text box change like textarea , can anyone say why issue rise?

Tags: html, google-chrome, input, safari, textbox

Safari browser , text box height scroll or text box change like textarea , can anyone say why issue rise ?

Html code (inspect element )

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 pull-right">  
  <input type="tel" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" placeholder="(+Country Code) - Area Code - Phone Number" name="alternate_mobile" ng-model="myModel.alternate_mobile">
</div>
```

Css code

```
textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="password"]{
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
background-image: none !important;
border: 1px solid #c8c7cc;
border-radius: 0;
color: #5b5b60 !important;
font-family: inherit !important;
font-size: 14px !important;
line-height: 1.2 !important;
padding: 5px 4px;
box-shadow: none !important;
resize: vertical !important;
```

}

```
.form-control {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 34px;}
```

[in chromer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5Z51.jpg) 
[in safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7Ass.jpg)

height change on drag 
suggestion - helps to retify this error and those faces issue in safari browser

Answer (score 0):

Yeah i found - why text box are vertically dragabble and shown as textarea in safari - 
they have given 
 **resize : vertical !important** , 
this troubling in safari browser and 
showing all text field as textarea